# How to create a conditional formatting rule that highlights a cell that checks for multiple values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rules, excel-2016

I'm looking to create rules that highlights various account numbers based on what they start with.

For instance, I want to highlight accounts that belong to the same group.  Some groups have multiple prefixes, others have one or two, and others have just one.

When creating rules, I select **Format only cells that contain**, **Specific Text**, and **beginning with**.

Lets assume the following:

- **Group A** prefixes: `109441`, `109221`, `108417`, `45897`
- **Group B** prefixes: `2451`, `291877`, `200000`
- **Group C** prefix: `49187`

If I want all of **Group A** to be filled in blue, I tried the following...

- Selecting a range of cells in another sheet (like if I were doing a validation)
- Entering `{109441,109221,108417,45897}`
- Entering `=OR(109441,109221,108417,45897)`
- Entering `=AND(109441,109221,108417,45897)`

And nothing highlights.
However, if I make 4 separate rules and just enter each prefix, it works.

Is there a way that I can avoid having to make a huge amount of rules?  The version of excel we use doesn't even let me duplicate rules, so I literally have to create one each time.  And I can't seem to make it apply to multiple sheets... so I'll have to do this for each tab in the workbook.  Yuck.

So far, any time I look for a solution, it talks about how to make multiple cells get affected by the rule.  I already can do that.  I just want a cell to be colored as long as it matches one of an arbitrary list of values (could be 1, could be 100).

I'm definitely stumped and can't figure anything else out now.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample screencap.

Comment: `=OR(A1={109441,109221,108417,45897})` or `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,{109441,109221,108417,45897},0))`  Where `A1` is the cell in the upper left of the applies to range.

Comment: @ScottCraner BbothOTH suggestion gives the error "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting Criteria."

Comment: ah, yes.  the second one should work though.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah, both does it.  I accidentally hit enter before I tried the second one...

Comment: Then you will need to use a range like the answer below. to hold the values and refer to that.

Comment: Didn't work either...  Is it something to do with Excel 2016, maybe?

Comment: Is "beginning with" strictly required over "contains?" Answer below edited for a "contains" condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up an auxiliary table that contains the values you wish to highlight, and then use the MATCH function as part of the condition.  Here is a screen cap of how I did it:

[image]

This works well because you can add more of your groups to the list later on.  The auxiliary table can be off to the side or in another sheet altogether.  The condition evaluates as TRUE when the IFERROR result is nonzero.

**EDIT:**
Here is a more general solution, not restricted to exact matches.
Using the cell references tried by the OP we should have,
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$22,$A1)))>0

Here is the formula in action from my end,
[image]

The only potential problem is that this looks at all text, i.e., is not restricted to a prefix only (as evidenced by cell A8 of the screenshot).

Comment: Doesn't work for me if the values are on another sheet such as: `=IFERROR(MATCH($A1,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$22,0),0)<>0` and it doesn't work in the same sheet, either...

Comment: Wait, is "MATCH" going to check for an exact match, or a prefix?

Comment: That method checked an exact match.  I see now you had asked about "cells beginning with."  I edited my answer to add another solution.  Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Going to see if I can't adapt it in a way to require nothing in front of those letters, however this will most likely be the best option for the time being.  Thank you!